# Identify a 320V DC Brushless IC Power MOSFET(?) Driver

Tags: identification, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver, reverse-engineering

I need some help identifying this IC. It comes from a bladeless fan.

It is presumably a 230V Power MOSFET(?) element connected to the FCM8201 Three-Phase Sine-Wave BLDC Motor Controller.

The thick top traces come from a capacitor connected to the rectified 230V AC.

More photos on the [EEVBlog Forum](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/bladeless-fan-repair-help-needed/).

[image: front view]
[image: back view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a FSB50250S chip (advertised as "smart power module"), containing 6 500V MOSFETS configured as three half-bridges, and including controllers.

Datasheet is [here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FSB50250S-1010056.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it seems so :) I will test the pinout against the datasheet and confirm. Unfortunately this IC is discontinued from what I see... Do you know of any replacements?

Comment: Arrow still seems to have some in stock: https://www.arrow.com/en/products/search?selectedType=product&q=FSB50250. Note that there seems to be multiple versions of this chip (with different packagings, and maybe other slight differences). I doubt you can find a replacement part with the same pinout and characteristics. It seems to be a very specific product.

Comment: Only FSB50250AB with totally different pinout. The SMD version in min qty of 450 pcs... But [FSB50450](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/fsb50450/fairchild-semiconductor) seems to be similar. I have to compare the datasheets.